# Titanium support for windows phone 10

Tags: windows-phone, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm trying to develop my first window phone app with Titanium. I have installed de wp 8.1 sdk and created a 'hello world' test app. I am able to launch this app in a windows phone 8 emulator (I launch it from appcelerator studio).

So far so good. Now I want to test the app on a device.
My windows phone has the windows phone 10 operating system.

My question is:
Is it possible to run an app which is developed for wp8 on a wp10 device. I expect the device to be backwards compatible but maybe it's not??

When I try to launch the ap on the device (from studio) I get this error:

Error: Not implemented
    at ChildProcess. (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.2.1.GA\node_modules\windowslib\lib\wptool.js:632:10)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)

Answer (score 1):

At present Appcelerator does not support Windows Phone 10. You can not build and run app on device with Windows 10 os form Appcelerator studio. Appcelerator team is working on it though.

Answer (score 1):

We'll introduce Windows 10 support in Titanium 5.3, which is now in beta:

http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2016/04/beta-releases-for-cli-5-3-titanium-5-3-and-studio-4-6/